# Redis storing ids in lists/sets

Tags: redis

Using redis, if I have a list of products such as top100 (where a product is a hashset and could belong to many lists such xmasideas, toprated etc..)

e.g. top100: ["product:2","product:234","product:3423",...,"product:7343"]

If I want to pull the first 10 items for top100 for display on say a webpage, is this the correct approach

1) Get the left range of the list 0 to 10, LRANGE top100 0 10
2) And then in iterate over the returned 10 ids and do a GET for each one
3) Project and display

Or does Redis provide a way to resolve the IDs to other keys server side?

Answer (score 0):

Currently Redis does not provide a way to resolve the IDs server side (the Lua scripting branch does -- but that is still experimental).

You can however do what you describe in two commands (Ruby):

```
top_10_ids = redis.lrange('top100', 0, 10)
top_10 = redis.mget(*top_10_ids)
```

i.e. do an `MGET` to retrieve all the values in one go -- but this assumes that the values are scalars. If the values are hashes you would have to iterate over each one and do a `HGETALL`, but you can take advantage pipelining (see http://redis.io/topics/pipelining) to speed it up.